# PHP Session variables lost either with www or without

Tags: php, session-variables

My site uses PHP sessions to keep track of a logged in user. Every page has session_start(); implemented properly, however in chrome when I place www. in from of the domain name it does not use the session variables. When I replace it back without the www. it works fine again, so the variables are not unset but rather just not being used.

In Firefox strangely it is the other way around. www. works and without does not. Is there a way around this? I'm having trouble because I'm using PayPal to redirect to my site and I can't have my users have to log out and back in directly after.

Comment: `www` is diferent with `without www` in terms of session cookie speaking. You should choose one. This is why sites such as SO forces their visitors to remove the www. And also, it's not a good practice to have two exactly-the-same websites on different (sub) domains.

Comment: It sounds like the session cookie is set to run under a specific domain.  I don't actually know how that's done, but you could check the session cookie settings.  Either that or just redirect from `www` (or back) every time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`www.example.com` and `example.com` are NOT the same website. They *usually* are, but only by convention. `www.example.com` is a subdomain of `example.com`

For this reason, cookies set on `example.com` will NOT be used on `www.example.com` and vice versa, because it would be unsafe to assume they are the same thing.

You can override this behaviour to some extent by allowing the session cookie to work on all subdomains as well as the main domain by setting the php.ini setting `session.cookie_domain` to `.example.com` (replace with your own domain name, of course)

Comment: Can be done on a per-script basis by calling [`session_set_cookie_params($lifetime, $path, $domain)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) before `session_start()`. Defaults would be: `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.mydomain.com');`

Answer (score 3):

You should either set the cookie_domain in PHP or make sure your users only see your site with www or without www. You can use .htaccess (apache server)  to accomplish this.

Example to set your cookie domain for multiple subdomains:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com'); 
session_start();
```